# how to use autocomplete field in jsp jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I am querying database to populate an input field and i am getting a long string returned from database so i want a single value from that string and other values to populate other input fields on selection, but unable to do so any help ?

Comment: what do you have so far? you can have an hidden input field with the all text, and make it visible when you want to read all the text. 
In order to do it, you can split the string into two input fields, the one is visible, and the second is the hidden one.

Comment: i am getting data from database as a long string, but i want to break it into various string to show in multiple input fields/

Comment: you have to know how you want to split the string, by size or by word number. put all substrings into an array, iterate over it, and create a input field for each one.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting a string from database, then try to breaking it into substrings at the server-side page. That way, you will have the short strings to be written in the responce.

If you want to write it using jQuery then use this

```
var name = "Afzaal Ahmad Zeeshan";
var words = name.substring(5); // this is basic js
```

This way you will get substrings of the long string, and then write it to the div elements.

Then you can add them to hidden elements, and on `click` you can show them using jQuery as

```
$('selector').click(function () {
 $('other_selector').show(); // show the other element
}
```

This way, you'll get the divs being shown which are substrings of a long string.